# Which of the following subsets of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ are compact?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Let $A ∈ M_n(\mathbb C)$ and let $\rho (A) = \max \{| \lambda| : \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A\}$ denote its spectral radius.

Which of the following subsets of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ are compact?

$a. S = \{A \in M_n(C) : ρ(A) ≤ 1\}$

$b. S = \{A ∈ M_n(C) : A = A^∗$ and $ρ(A) ≤ 1\}$

$c. S = \{A ∈ M_n(C) : AA^∗ = A^∗A = I\}$

I have proved that part $c$ is compact. But cannot conclude about the other parts.

Comment: Judging by the phrasing of the question, I can immediately guess that a is probably not compact, but b probably is.

Comment: yes c is compact and i have done it

Answer (score 1):

Consider matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ for different $n$..

These matrices have eigenvalues $1$.. But matrix norm can be as large as you wish..  So, subspace in question $1$ is not compact